# Computed property that depends on another computed property

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

Code below yields error "Cannot read property 'form' of undefined":

```
computed: {
  boundary_limits () {
    return this.$refs.hemoBoundaryLimits.form;
  },
  high_risk_alerts () {
    return this.$refs.highRiskAlerts.form;
  },
  alerts () {
    return {
      boundary_limits: this.boundary_limits,
      high_risk_alerts: this.high_risk_alerts
    }
  }
}
```

Yet if I removed `alerts()`, I get no error and I can even console log `boundary_limits` or `high_risk_alerts` 
 successfully, which means `$refs.hemoBoundaryLimits` and `this.$refs.highRiskAlerts` *are* defined.

So Vue.js has a problem with how I define `alerts`, but I see no problem in it.

Any clue what's going on?

Comment: What exactly error do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes because you are trying to access `$refs` in computed property.
Computed properties are evaluated before the template is mounted and thus the `hemoBoundaryLimits` is `undefined`.

You should access `$refs` in the mounted hook.

As solution, you can trick it by knowing when the component is mounted using `@hook` event:

```
<hemoBoundaryLimits @hook:mounted="isHemoBoundaryLimitsMounted = true" />
```

And in the script

```
data: () => ({
  isHemoBoundaryLimitsMounted: false
}),

computed: {
  boundary_limits () {
    if (!this.isHemoBoundaryLimitsMounted) return
    return this.$refs.hemoBoundaryLimits.form;
  }
}
```